# Understanding the declaration of formGroup in angular 4 forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am new to angular, and in the documentation i have learned that to pass data from the parent to the child we use the input decoration like this

```
export class demo {
  @input()
  someInput: any;
}
```

and we pass the data from the parent to the child like this

```
<div *ngFor='let data of moreData'>
<child-component [someData]='data'></child-component>
</div>
```

now my question is, when we use the formGroup in the reactive form approach, we use

> [formGroup]='form'

but why is the @input()formGroup:FormGroup tag not necessary for the component holding the form, am i missing something, if yes, please let me know

Comment: it wasn't necessary neither in the parent component of your first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not adding `[formGroup]` on the component holding the form. You're adding it on the `<form>` element. So it can't be an input of your component.

The formGroup attribute is the selector of the [`FormGroupDirective`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupDirective). And this directive has an [input named formGroup](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.0.1/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_group_directive.ts#L74).

So, by adding the formGroup attribute to an element, you trigger the instanciation of the FormGroupDirective, and by passing a value of type FormGroup as the value of this attribute, you pass the form group to the input of this directive.

Comment: #1 how can the name of the directive and the input be same
#2 how can just mentioning the property of a directive can instantiate the directive
can you provide me some link to help me understand this, thank you for the help

Comment: #1 because there's nothing preventing that in the framework (and it's actually a desired feature, to be able to trigger the directive and pass information with a single attribute); #2 It'snot a property of the directive. It's the CSS selector of the directive. `foo` means an element `<foo>`. `[foo]` means an attribute `foo`, `.foo` means a class `foo`. You're using such directives all the time: ngStyle, ngClass, ngModel, formGroup, formControlName, etc.

Comment: thank you very much, your answer was very helpful for me